# $PUSH into a Subdoc array in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following model:

```
var Customer = mongoose.model('Customer', {
    firstname : String,
    lastname : String,
    phone : String,
    street : String,
    city : String,
    state : String,
    zip : String,
    fixed : Boolean,
    readings: [
        {
            reading: Number,
            date: String
        }],
    billing: {
        charges: [Number],
        payments: [Number]
    }
});
```

Im trying to add individual charges and payments to billing.

I am using the following code but doesn't seem to be updating....

```
   Customer.update({_id: req.params.cust_id},
       { billing: { $push:{charges: 100}, $push:{payments:50}}},
       {upsert:true},
       function(err, customer){
           if(err){
               console.log(err);
           }
           else{
               Customer.findOne({
                   _id : req.params.cust_id
               }, function(err, customer) {
                   if (err)
                       res.send(err);
                   res.json(customer);
               });
           }
       }
   )
```

IF anyone has any suggestions they would be greatly appreciated. Ive found a lot of examples of $push but all seem to be on the top level and not a subdoc.

Comment: how can i do this for creating new record, becoz am stucking with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dot notation for the fields, which are an argument to $push

```
Customer.update({_id: req.params.cust_id},
   { $push: { "billing.charges": 100, "billing.payments": 50} },
   {upsert:true},
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked with dot notation however I had to combine the statements into one push statement: 
{ $push: { "billing.charges": 100, "billing.payments": 50} }

Comment: @BrentAureli you shouldn't **have** to. But it looks better. I was a little too fast with cut and paste.

Comment: Ah, it must have been a problem on my end then. I was getting Cant execute $push on non arrays error on the second property, but once I changed it to the single statement it worked. It musta just been a typo on my part.